# How to know which content script communicates with the background in a Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, background, firefox-addon, messaging, content-script

According to [this simple example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Connection-based_messaging):
how to know which content script (which tab) is actually sending a message to the background (line 10)? For example with the tab id.

Comment: My solution is to use `browser.tabs.onCreated` in the background, immediately send the tab id to the content script and save it in the content script. But it's ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Connection-based_messaging) for background-script.js, the `portFromCS` has a sender property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/Port

That sender is an object which contains `tab` and in particular `tab.id`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/MessageSender

```
/* background-script.js */
browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
    port.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
        console.log("bg received", msg, "from tab", port.sender.tab.id);
    });
});
```

You can also do "one-off" or connection-less messages with
`browser.runtime.onMessage`

the handler has signature `(msg, sender, reply)`, where sender is the same MessageSender object as above.

Comment: Yes thank you it works. I can use `sender.tab.id` in `browser.runtime.onMessage`. One-of messages offer more possibilities. But I have to be careful because when a message is sent from the background, it's also received in the background, so I have to check the content of the message to ensure it's a message from the content script.

Comment: @hayj, What version of Firefox are you using where receiving an event for the message you send from the same script is a problem? As far as I'm aware, that is a bug which was resolved as of Firefox 51. Are you seeing it in Firefox 51 or a later version?

Comment: I am on 51.0.1 (64 bits), let me check if it's not my bad.

Comment: No it's ok I have to use `browser.tabs.sendMessage` instead of `browser.runtime.sendMessage` in the background so it send the message only to the specified tab.

Comment: edited answer: removed wrong "gut-feeling": port.onMessage handler can not include sender. Added a short example for future reference too.